# overlap cells in table

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

[image: screenshot table]

I've created a table in XSLT where I use XSL-fo for some objects. In this case  I would like to place the image behind the text above the green line.
In the screenshot you see that the second textline is cut in half, but I want to show the textline in the right way, without moving the image downwards.
I've tried z-index, block-containers, background-images, padding, but I've no solution yet.

The image is in a table-cell, as well as the text. The green line is in fact the background color of the table-cell of the image.

---

```
<fo:block break-before="auto"/>
<fo:block keep-together="auto" ><!-- GENERATE TABLE START-->
<xsl:if test="Product[count(ProductID) &gt; 0]">
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt">
<fo:table-column column-width="10.0mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="24.5mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="3.0mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="4.0mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="48.5mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="4.0mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="48.5mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="31.0mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="10.0mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="5.8mm"/>

<!--header-->
<fo:table-header>
<fo:table-row height="5.0mm">
<!--empty cell-->
    <fo:table-cell/>
<!--header 1-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="69.7pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block line-height="10.799999999999999pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="4.26791pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.41848pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger LT 57 Condensed" font-size="9.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
            <xsl:text>Suitable for</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="8.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
<!--header 2-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.41848pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger LT 87 Extra Black Condensed" font-size="9.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
            <xsl:text>Description</xsl:text></fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
<!--header 3-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="138.0pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block line-height="10.799999999999999pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="-5.6999pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.41848pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger LT 57 Condensed" font-size="9.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
        <fo:block text-align="left" white-space-collapse="false"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve" >
        <fo:inline padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="-5.6999pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.41848pt">
            <xsl:text>Details</xsl:text>
        </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
<!--header 4-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="88.20354pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block line-height="10.799999999999999pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="11.4pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.41848pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger LT 57 Condensed" font-size="9.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
            <xsl:text>Replaces</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
<!--header 5-->
    <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="28.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
        <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="7.7pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.41848pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger LT 87 Extra Black Condensed" font-size="9.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
            <xsl:text>No.</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>

<fo:table-body>
<xsl:for-each select="Product[count(ProductID) &gt; 0]">
<!--empty cells-->
    <fo:table-row height="0.0pt">
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always">
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--content concerning 'Suitable for'-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="14" display-align="before" width="69.7pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="11.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="4.26791pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="7.1pt" display-align="before">

<!--some code-->    

            </fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--language blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="2" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.84527pt" display-align="before">

<!--some code-->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--concent concerning 'Details'-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="138.0pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
            <fo:block line-height="10.799999999999999pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.78245pt" start-indent="-5.6999pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="6.5pt" text-align="start" background-color="transparent" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger 57 Condensed" font-size="9.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="no" select="Matchcode"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--content concerning 'Replaces'-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="88.20354pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="11.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-after-linefeed"  hyphenate="true" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="6.5pt" display-align="before">
                <xsl:call-template name="tmpManufacturer_ref"></xsl:call-template>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--content concerning 'No.'-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="28.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
            <fo:block white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="5.69055pt" text-align="end" background-color="transparent" keep-together="auto"  color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Frutiger LT 87 Extra Black Condensed" font-size="11.0pt" letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="no" select="ProductID"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>


    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--product images-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="13" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="center" width="138.0pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/DocumentURL,'_LL') and Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/UsageTypeID = 'normal'">
                <fo:block position="relative" text-align="center" padding-top="2.0mm" padding-bottom="-2.0mm" display-align="center" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpBildLL" />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/DocumentURL,'_L') and Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/UsageTypeID = 'normal'">     
                <fo:block position="relative" text-align="center" display-align="center" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpBildL" />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/DocumentURL,'_M') and Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/UsageTypeID = 'normal'">
                <fo:block position="relative" text-align="center" display-align="center" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpBildM" />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/DocumentURL,'_KK') and Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/UsageTypeID = 'normal'">
                <fo:block position="relative" text-align="center" display-align="center" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpBildKK" />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/DocumentURL,'_K') and Documents/Document/DocumentAssets/DocumentAsset/UsageTypeID = 'normal'">
                <fo:block position="relative" text-align="center" display-align="center" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpBildK" />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:block position="relative" text-align="center" display-align="center" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpBildUnisize" />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--image QR code-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="11" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="28.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="end" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed"  hyphenate="true" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.8pt" display-align="before">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(QR_CODE) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="tmpQRCode" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row height="0.71131pt" keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" keep-with-previous.within-column="always" keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--language blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
<!--some code>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row height="0.71131pt" keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" keep-with-previous.within-column="always" keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--language blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="2" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
<!--some code>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous="always">   
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row height="0.71131pt" keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" keep-with-previous.within-column="always" keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--lanuguage blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="2" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
<!--some code>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row height="0.7113pt" keep-with-next="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--language blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="2" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
<!--some code-->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row height="0.71131pt" keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next="always" keep-with-previous="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--language blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
<!--some code-->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row height="0.71131pt" keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next.within-line="always" keep-with-next.within-column="always" keep-with-next.within-page="always" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" keep-with-previous.within-column="always" keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--code for generating page number-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-rows-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="8.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
                <fo:block id="{generate-id(.)}"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell/>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-line="always" keep-together.within-column="always" keep-together.within-page="always" keep-with-next.within-line="always" keep-with-next.within-column="always" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
<!--empty cell-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
<!--language blocks-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">

<!--some code-->

            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--code for generating page numbers-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="11.4pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
                <xsl:call-template name="tmpOEM" />
                <xsl:call-template name="tmpOEM_other" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--Special product-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="28.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="11.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed"  hyphenate="true" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="2.8453pt" display-align="before">

<!--some code-->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
<!--New Product-->
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before" width="16.5pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block position="relative" text-align="start" color="rgb-icc(0,0,0, #CMYK, 0.65,0.53,0.51,1.0)" font-family="Arial" font-size="11.0pt" white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="true" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" display-align="before">
                <xsl:if test="NewInCat='Y'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="TemplateNEW"></xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row keep-with-previous="always">
<!--empty cells-->
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.30001pt" border-bottom-color="rgb-icc(1,1,1, #CMYK, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)" padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="0.0pt" padding="0.0pt" number-columns-spanned="9" display-align="before" width="69.7pt"  reference-orientation="0">
            <fo:block break-before="auto"/>
            <fo:block white-space-collapse="false"  linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve"  hyphenate="false" language="en"  padding-bottom="0.0pt" start-indent="0.0pt" end-indent="0.0pt" padding-top="5.7pt" text-align="start" keep-together="auto"  letter-spacing="normal" word-spacing="normal">
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="auto"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>

</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</xsl:if>
</fo:block>
<fo:block break-after="auto"/>
```

Comment: Could you add to the question a relevant fragmant of your FO file (such as your table limited to a single row / a few rows showing the problem)? It would allow people to spot the problem in your approach, and / or suggest a solution that is similar to what you have done (= probably easier to integrate in your xslt).

Comment: Without seeing the XSL FO, it is really hard to make suggestions. BUT, it you wish an image to be behind the text of a table cell, then put that image in as the background-image to a table cell or table or other structure like the block-container of the text.

Comment: You should also post what processor you are using. Some have extreme issues using background-images and I suspect that is your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using background-image on the table-cell or on a block-container inside the table cell works for me. This code:

```
 <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column column-width="4.7in"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell background-image="test.jpg" height="2.3in" border-top="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border-top="1pt solid black" >
                        <fo:block-container background-image="test.jpg" height="2.3in">
                            <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                            <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                            <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                            <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                            <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                            <fo:block text-align="right">I am some text in the table cell. </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

Results in this image below. You can see that the text overlaps the image as I made it do so intentionally. You could of course control the image through no-repeat. The only limitation would be sizing the image (if it needed to be controlled) unless you use a renderer that supports background-image scaling. RenderX supports this, I am not sure Apache FOP does.

[image]

Comment: I verified that this indeed works with Apache FOP, tested using FOP 1.0 but forum posts on coderanch have reported that this works on versions as early as 0.25.

Comment: I also verified it works with FOP, my comment is more toward whether the OP wishes to "scale" the image in anyway. I do not know if FOP support such things as applying image scaling on a background image. As is, the issue with this solution would be to use the image as a background image and scale it as needed. AFAIK, RenderX supports scaling background images extensions but I do not know if FOP does.